# Get javascript multidimensional array from form using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to store multidimensional array, taken from an HTML form, into javascript array.

I have this simple form:

```
        <label for="radek_predpisu_1">První řádek předpisu</label>
        <input type="text" name="predpisy[text][]" id="text_predpisu_1" value="" maxlength="100" size="60" title="Text předpisu" placeholder="Text předpisu" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <input type="text" name="predpisy[cena][]" id="cena_predpisu_1" value="" maxlength="4" size="4" title="Cena bez DPH" placeholder="Cena bez DPH" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <input type="text" name="predpisy[pocet][]" id="pocet_predpisu_1" value="" maxlength="4" size="4" title="Počet jednotek" placeholder="Počet jednotek" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
```

Now I use:

```
var predpisy = $('[name="predpisy"]');
```

What should I do next? If I try to `alert( predpisy['text'][0]` and I got `undefined`.

Thank you very much.

Radek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('[name="predpisy"]')` is only going to give you elements whose name exactly matches the string 'predpisy'.

What you want is this: `$('[name*="predpisy"]')`, which will select all elements whose name contains 'predpisy', which I think is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I didnt know it, but it still returns undefined.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do now. I'm not sure jQuery works that way that you expect it to. You can try something like `$('[name*="predpisy[text][]"]')[0]`

Comment: `$('[name*="predpisy"]')` will give you an array of your text fields, but you will have to reference them by their index, e.g.:

    var predpisy = $('[name*="predpisy"]')
    alert(predpisy[0])

Answer (score 0):

```
var predpisy = $('[name^="predpisy"]');
console.log(predpisy[0]['text']);
console.log(predpisy[0]['cena']);
console.log(predpisy[0]['pocet']);
```

Comment: This is, what I am trying too - I got undefined also.

Comment: Updated. try once.

Comment: Still the same, but I think, that should be predpisy['text'][0] , but it also doesnt work.

Comment: what is the output for console.log(predpisy)

Comment: Object { length: 15, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → index.php, selector: "[name^="predpisy"]", 15 more… }